# How To Limit Python Memory Usage?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

Currently i'm working at Python Project, and i have a 2.12 GB model which has to be processed.

This is the code :

```
model = PegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("google/pegasus-xsum")
```

that code had to be running.

I tried with my own PC 8GB RAM, and it works perfectly, but in my VPS i only has 1GB RAM and it always killed the proccess because lack of memory.
How can i limit Python Memory Usage so i could run that 2.12GB model?

Comment: Smaller model or more RAM.

Comment: Limiting the memory usage will not fix your problem

Comment: You can make a swap file that would "emulate" more RAM by using hard drive, but the speed will be terrible

Comment: how can i do the "emulate" thing?

Comment: I think this is like asking *How do I get a quart into a pint pot?*

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE :**

Someone told me to do "emulate" more RAM by using hard drive, and i did this tutorial with my VPS : https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Link above is tutorial how to add SWAP or add more RAM from your Hard Disk.

I added 5GB SWAP and it really run the program, but the speed is sooooooo slow, just like he told me before.
even when i write this Answer (About 20 Mins), it still loading the process LMAO.

Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: This is not an answer